# Get next value of array depending on current one

Tags: php

I've got this code :

```
$array1 = array("2018-02-01" => "10", "2018-03-01" => "20");
$array2 = array("2018-01-01" => "random", "2018-02-01" => "random", "2018-03-01" => "random", "2018-04-01" => "random");

$end_array = array();

$v = 0;
foreach($array2 as $key => $value) {

    if($array1[$key]) {
        $v = intval($array1[$key]);
        $end_array[] = $v;
    } else {
        $end_array[] = $v;
    }
}

var_dump($end_array);
```

Which is giving me this output :

```
array(4) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(10) [2]=> int(20) [3]=> int(20) }
```

But I want to get this output :

```
array(4) { [0]=> int(10) [1]=> int(20) [2]=> int(20) [3]=> int(20) }
```

In other words, I want to assign the value of the current array to the previous one.

I tried looking for ways to check if the key of the next array is a key in my `array1` but it still didn't give me the right output (or rather I don't think I correctly checked, I can't seem to find the right algorithm). I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Not sure of the logic but instead of `$v = 0;` how about `$v = reset($array1);`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver this would work if it only needed for the first one, but since `I want to assign the value of the current array to the previous one `this is not what he is asking

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: i did not understand in a first place.
Basically you can just handle your id and just change the last element if it exist in the first array

```
$end_array = array();
$id = 0;
$v = 0;
foreach($array2 as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($array1[$key])) {
        $v = intval($array1[$key]);
        $end_array[$id] = $v;
        if(isset($end_array[$id-1]))
        {
            $end_array[$id-1] = $v;
        }
    } else {
        $end_array[$id] = $v;
    }
$id++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do but you can check if the key exists with the array_key_exists() function. [More info](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

Comment: This doesn't help me at all but thank you for your comment.